# Using a for loop on a dict to change/ update the first value using the index

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

Let's say I have this dictionary.

```
mydict = {"abc":[1, 2, 3], "def":[4, 5, 6], "ghi":[7, 8, 9]}
```

I can't get my head around how I use a for loop in this case to update only the first number by +1. So essentially the outcome would be:

```
mydict = {"abc":[2, 2, 3], "def":[5, 5, 6], "ghi":[8, 8, 9]}
```

Searching online I cannot seem to find how to do this with an index and the +1. The only thing I find is, if the values are known how to replace them, or if the keys are known that those are written down, like this:

```
mydict["abc"] = [2, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Do you mean: `for numbers in mydict.values(): numbers[0] += 1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to modify the *dict*, only the lists contained within it (its values).

```
for nums in mydict.values():
    nums[0] += 1
```

`mydict` is then:

```
{'abc': [2, 2, 3], 'def': [5, 5, 6], 'ghi': [8, 8, 9]}
```

Lists are mutable, which means they can be modified instead of replaced (as opposed to, say, tuples).

Answer (score 2):

It's simple:

```py
mydict = {"abc": [1, 2, 3], "def": [4, 5, 6], "ghi": [7, 8, 9]}

for key in mydict:
    mydict[key][0] += 1

print(mydict)
```

Prints:

```
{'abc': [2, 2, 3], 'def': [5, 5, 6], 'ghi': [8, 8, 9]}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you like the one-liner solutions, then you can use the following:

```py
{k: [v[0] + 1] + v[1:] for k, v in mydict.items()}
```

**A minimal test code:**

```
mydict_1 = {"abc": [1, 2, 3], "def": [4, 5, 6], "ghi": [7, 8, 9]}
mydict_2 = {"abc": [1, 2, 3, 4, 6], "def": [4, 5], "ghi": [0, 8, 9]}

mydict_1 = {k: [v[0] + 1] + v[1:] for k, v in mydict_1.items()}
mydict_2 = {k: [v[0] + 1] + v[1:] for k, v in mydict_2.items()}

print(mydict_1)
print(mydict_2)
```

**Output:**

```
{'abc': [2, 2, 3], 'def': [5, 5, 6], 'ghi': [8, 8, 9]}
{'abc': [2, 2, 3, 4, 6], 'def': [5, 5], 'ghi': [1, 8, 9]}
```

As you can see above the one-liner can handle the different size of lists, so it's a generic solution.

Comment: Just to be clear, the other answers also handle different sizes of lists.

Comment: OP's saying they want to modify `mydict`, but this creates a **new** dict. You could reassign `mydict` to get the same effect though.

Comment: Thanks for your finding, I have just edited my answer. Sure, other answers also can handle the different sizes of lists, I just wanted to mark that the one-liner doesn't have limitation about it.

Comment: This needlessly copies each value (slicing a list creates a copy). It is both less efficient and less readable, and has no advantage over a simple for-loop. Downvote!

Comment: I didn't say that it's the most efficient solution for it... There are other very nice solutions in other answers, the OP can select the optimal one. I just wanted to show an another approach as a one-liner. But OFC, I accept your decision about downvote. :)